# mysql fetch previous or next record order by anyother field name and not by using order by id

Tags: mysql

I am displaying a list.

The user can edit any item.

I am displaying next previous buttons which when clicked it dynamically fetches the next previous records form db. no page reload.

this is working well with id. like [how can i get next and previous field id with php from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780642/how-can-i-get-next-and-previous-field-id-with-php-from-mysql) **and** [MySQL next/previous ids (arbitrary sort order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528806/mysql-next-previous-ids-arbitrary-sort-order)

Currently i am displaying like

> select * from table order by name asc

and for next and previous i used like this...

```
select * from table where id > $id order by name asc limit 1
select * from table where id < $id order by name desc limit 1
```

the above is what i got when i searched the internet.

in this order the id will not be in an order so i cannot use id to fetch next and previous record i think so.

i want to get next and previous records with respect to any other field and not by id.

so some thing like this.

> select * from table where id > 5 order
>   by name asc or desc limit 1.

what would be the query?

**Note**

There are 15000 records. which is half filled by default. the rest half is supposed to be updated by admin. so instead of reloading the page after the admin had updated one record i fetch the other and show dynamically on the screen so that he can continue updating content. there will not any page reload. he just clicks update and the next record appears. he can select previous or next button to navigate between records.

Comment: select * from table where id > 5 order by name asc or desc limit 1. should work, considering that you use asc or desc, not both.

Comment: no. it is working but not as expected. yeah the or is in quoted text and not as a code so i used it for just an indication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to filter on the value of name:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE name < 'Foo'
ORDER by name DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This only works if the names are unique. If there can be duplicates you need a tie-breaker. You can for example use the id column to tie-break.

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE name < 'Foo' OR (name = 'Foo' AND id < 42)
ORDER by name DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I agree, binding is the best approach and is essentially intelligent escaping.

Comment: My point was that your original answer had $name in the SQL without and indication that more needed to be done.

Comment: sooperappu. working well. thank you. yes i had escaped by default. when ever there is a post then first i use xss_clean and remove all slashes if any and then use mysql real escape string

Answer (score 0):

You're better doing more tradition pagination.

```
$itemsPerPage = 10;

$page = (int)$_GET['page'];  // do more validation to check this is a valid integer

$start = ($page * $itemsPerPage) - $itemsPerPage;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`WHERE name < ? ORDER by name DESC limit $start, $itemsPerPage";
```

Comment: no. there are 15000 records. which is half filled by default. the rest half is supposed to be updated by admin. so instead of reloading the page after the admin had updated one record i fetch the other and show dynamically on the screen so that he can continue updating content. there will not any page reload. he just clicks update and the next record appears. he can select previous or next button to navigate between records.